# Can I use an Ethernet switch IC without connecting to the mcu?

Tags: integrated-circuit, ethernet, pcie, sgmii, rgmii

I'd like to add an unmanaged Ethernet switch IC to a board I am designing, but I have no free RGMII/SGMII/PCIe connection available on my MCU. The goal of this IC is just to save space/hassle (in the application I am targeting, I cannot afford to have an external switch, so I have to integrate everything on this board). No need for me to configure it or whatever, it simply has to link the devices connected to it (and, since one of its port will be directly connected to an MCU's Ethernet port, also to the MCU).

Is it still mandatory to connect it (via RGMII/SGMII/PCIe/...) to the MCU or can I skip the connection entirely? It is not that clear to me after reading several datasheets... Any reference to the literature is more than welcome.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the datasheet of the part you intend to use?

Comment: I'll be using a Jetson TX2i as microcontroller, for the switch I am open to any alternative (it could be for instance the VSC 7511 from microsemi -- https://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/ethernet-switches/3989-vsc7511)